# Ajax Load Data Button and Links not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with jQuery Ajax load. On message.php, it shows messages and it has copy and delete link. When I click on delete, it deletes the message from the mysqli database. But when I use `ajax.load('message.php')` to load the message.php page, the delete link does not work at all.

Is there a way for me to click hyperlink or button from `the ajax.load()`?

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#loadBtn').click(function() {          
    $('#messageDiv').load('message.php');
  });

});
</script>
```

```
<div id="messageDiv"></div>
```

Here is my message.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id='delete'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' id='id'>
    <button id='delete'> Delete </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php


    $conn_database = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','content','message');
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_database, $_POST['id']);

    $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM message WHERE id = $id";

    mysqli_query($conn_database, $sql_delete);


?>
```

Comment: Is the delete link also using AJAX?

Comment: Hi, you should also put the code of your message.php file, i think that <script>'s contained inside your message.php page aren't executed when the `.load()` method finishes, the `.load()` method simply puts the HTML code into the div but won't execute the js <script>'s found in the HTML, hence the delete link delete handler wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: @ankabot, JavaScript should load as long as you don't use a selector along with the page.

Comment: @StackSlave I meant if you have a `<script>alert('ok')</script>` in the message.php file, and from another file you jQuery `.load()` the message.php file would you see the 'ok' pops in, i don't think so but i'm not sure since i didn't tested.

Comment: Your page executing the `.load()`, needs to update itself in its complete function argument.

Comment: add your delete link script too.

Comment: I have updated the message.php file. Can someone please show me why message.php button/hyperlink not working when it is loaded from ajax.load()?

Comment: @StackSlave what do you mean by the load() needs to update itself? I have the message.php file in the question.